# OpenCV. Fail after re-installing system

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

The program throw exception with the messages:

1) "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\OpenCV\sources\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3737".

2) "OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in cv::arithm_op, file C:\OpenCV\sources\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp, line 1287".

It seems that Qt telling me, that problem in dialog.cpp file, while conversions

```
cv::cvtColor(frame1, GrayConvrt1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::cvtColor(frame2, GrayConvrt2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

**But, the most strange, that it works fine with that part of code for 5-10 sec. How to resolve the problem?**

Answer (score 1):

Solution: cameras driver's installation.

Answer (score 1):

The image you capture from the camera could be empty (no camera detected) or in black and white (error in the drivers ?).
You should check the number of channels of your images before trying the conversion.